# Identifying changes between two data frames

Tags: r

[Please see this link to see original question and code:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94253/identify-changes-between-two-data-frames-explain-deltas-for-x-columns)

Manually went through code. Saved M so I can read it again and continue. With the following code snippets, you should be able to replicate issue after downloading csv.

```
fileUrl <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kill3rbee/NTS-Test/master/test-2016-12-30.csv"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "test.csv")
M <- read.csv("test.csv")

KEYS = c("ShortFileName")
VAL = c("scanDate","Count")
retain.columns = c("Category","OwaspTop10","Severity","scanDate", 
                   "Count", "DaysLate")

####################testing code#################################
# this will be our output
O <- M[KEYS]

# add rows.changed
O$row.changed <- with(M, ifelse(is.old & is.new, "10.Retained",
                                ifelse(is.old, "05.Lost", "00.New")))

# add data from new
original.vars <- retain.columns
for (var in original.vars)
  O[[var]] <- M[[paste0(var, ".new")]]
```

At this point I get the following after adding new data:

```
ShortFileName   Category.new    OwaspTop10.new  Severity.new    scanDate.new    Count.new   DaysLate.new    is.new  Category.old    OwaspTop10.old  Severity.old    scanDate.old    Count.old   DaysLate.old    is.old
_posix.py   Command Injection   A01-Injection   High    12/5/2016   4   15  TRUE    Command Injection   A01-Injection   High    10/25/2016  4   56  TRUE
11_ro.jsp   Cross-Site Request Forgery  A08-CSRF    Medium  11/16/2016  4   34  TRUE    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE
aais_agent.C    Integer Overflow    NA  High    12/2/2016   3   18  TRUE    Insecure Compiler Optimization  NA  Low 10/13/2016  1   68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Integer Overflow    NA  High    12/2/2016   3   18  TRUE    Buffer Overflow: Format String  NA  High    10/13/2016  6   68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Integer Overflow    NA  High    12/2/2016   3   18  TRUE    Dangerous Function: strcpy()    NA  Low 10/13/2016  342 68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Integer Overflow    NA  High    12/2/2016   3   18  TRUE    String Termination Error    NA  High    10/13/2016  834 68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Integer Overflow    NA  High    12/2/2016   3   18  TRUE    Integer Overflow    NA  High    10/13/2016  3   68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Insecure Compiler Optimization  NA  Low 12/2/2016   1   18  TRUE    Unchecked Return Value  NA  Low 10/13/2016  11  68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Buffer Overflow: Format String  NA  Critical    12/2/2016   12  18  TRUE    String Termination Error    NA  High    10/13/2016  834 68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    Buffer Overflow: Format String  NA  Critical    12/2/2016   12  18  TRUE    Integer Overflow    NA  High    10/13/2016  3   68  TRUE
aais_agent.C    String Termination Error    NA  High    12/2/2016   1377    18  TRUE    Unchecked Return Value  NA  Low 10/13/2016  11  68  TRUE



ShortFileName   Category.new    OwaspTop10.new  Severity.new    scanDate.new    Count.new   DaysLate.new    is.new  Category.old    OwaspTop10.old  Severity.old    scanDate.old    Count.old   DaysLate.old    is.old
xmlTranscode.cpp    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Buffer Overflow: Format String  NA  High    10/13/2016  1   68  TRUE
xmlTranscode.cpp    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Path Manipulation   NA  Critical    10/13/2016  1   68  TRUE
XMLUtils.java   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Path Manipulation   NA  High    10/20/2016  4   61  TRUE
XSLHelper.java  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    10/24/2016  1   57  TRUE
XslMerger.java  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    10/10/2016  1   71  TRUE
XsltGen.java    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Path Manipulation   NA  High    10/25/2016  2   56  TRUE
yui-bridge.js   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Cross-Site Request Forgery  A08-CSRF    Medium  10/21/2016  2   60  TRUE
yuitest-debug.js    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Cross-Site Request Forgery  A08-CSRF    Medium  10/25/2016  1   56  TRUE
yuitest.js  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  FALSE   Cross-Site Request Forgery  A08-CSRF    Medium  10/25/2016  1   56  TRUE
```

When I run code below:

```
# modify data for retain.columns
# Columns for which the NAs should be 
# filled with the 'old' data if rows were lost
# These columns have row.changed value of "05.Lost"
for (var in retain.columns)
  O[[var]] <- ifelse(M$is.new, M[[paste0(var, ".new")]],
                     M[[paste0(var, ".old")]])
```

I get the following output:

```
ShortFileName   row.changed Category    OwaspTop10  Severity    scanDate    Count   DaysLate
XSLTTransformer.java    00.New  35  1   2   8   9   23
XsltUtils.java  10.Retained 35  1   2   15  1   16
XSLUtil.java    10.Retained 35  1   2   1   1   58
XSLXReader.java 10.Retained 21  NA  2   19  3   83
XSLXReader.java 10.Retained 21  NA  2   13  3   18
XSSFilter.java  00.New  23  NA  3   4   4   33
XSSFilter.java  00.New  25  NA  3   4   9   33
XSSFilter.java  00.New  19  NA  3   4   2   33
Zoom.java   10.Retained 21  NA  1   14  4   17
Zoom.java   10.Retained 21  NA  1   14  4   17
Zoom.java   10.Retained 9   3   1   14  4   17
Zoom.java   10.Retained 9   3   1   14  4   17
XmlGenericParser.java   05.Lost 33  NA  2   11  1   56
yui-bridge.js   05.Lost 13  5   4   7   2   60
yuitest-debug.js    05.Lost 13  5   4   11  1   56
yuitest.js  05.Lost 13  5   4   11  1   56
```

It works with mtcars data based on original post link above. However, with my type of data, it is not working.

I do not understand why it creates a dataframe with numbers in them?

I have been trying to figure out a way to just copying old data with *.old suffix column.

I tried something like so and it works:

```
# add data from new
original.vars <- retain.columns
for (var in original.vars)
  if(O$row.changed=="00.New"||O$row.changed=="10.Retained"){
    O[[var]] <- M[[paste0(var, ".new")]]
  }
```

However, this does not work:

```
# add data from old to Lost
original.vars <- retain.columns
for (var in original.vars)
  if(O$row.changed=="05.Lost"&& is.na(O$Category)){
    O[[var]] <- M[[paste0(var, ".old")]]
  }
```

This is an example of expected outcome:

```
ShortFileName   row.changed Category    OwaspTop10  Severity    scanDate    Count   DaysLate
AbstractCorbaIntf.java  00.New  Poor Error Handling: Empty Catch Block  NA  Low 11/17/2016  1   33
AbstractCorbaIntf.java  00.New  Poor Error Handling: Overly Broad Catch NA  Low 11/17/2016  3   33
AbstractCorbaIntf.java  00.New  System Information Leak NA  Low 11/17/2016  2   33
AbstractDaemon.java 00.New  System Information Leak NA  Low 11/2/2016   1   48
AbstractDaemon.java 00.New  Unchecked Return Value  NA  Low 11/2/2016   1   48
AbstractDatabaseLoader.java 10.Retained Path Manipulation   NA  High    12/5/2016   1   15
AbstractEventListener.java  00.New  Poor Error Handling: Overly Broad Catch NA  Low 11/2/2016   1   48
AbstractEventListener.java  00.New  System Information Leak NA  Low 11/2/2016   1   48
AbstractEventListener.java  00.New  Unsafe Reflection   NA  Low 11/2/2016   2   48
AbstractHostKeyVerification.java    10.Retained XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    11/28/2016  1   22
AbstractLertFaxController.java  00.New  Often Misused: File Upload  NA  Medium  10/31/2016  1   50
AbstractLertFaxController.java  00.New  Path Manipulation   NA  Critical    10/31/2016  1   50
AbstractMastarsCorbaClientTest.java 10.Retained Path Manipulation   NA  High    11/22/2016  6   28
AbstractTemplateVariableParser.java 10.Retained XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    12/4/2016   2   16
AbstractTemplateVariableParser.java 10.Retained XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    12/5/2016   1   15
AbstractTransformerQueryProcessor.java  00.New  Poor Logging Practice: Use of a System Output Stream    NA  Low 11/2/2016   2   48
AbstractXMLDOMConfigurator.java 10.Retained XML External Entity Injection   A01-Injection   High    12/4/2016   2   16
axis2.xml   05.Lost Axis 2 Misconfiguration: Debug Information  A05-Security Misconfig  Medium  10/24/2016  8   57
axis2.xml   05.Lost Axis 2 Misconfiguration: Insecure Message Security  A05-Security Misconfig  Medium  10/23/2016  2   58
axis2.xml   05.Lost Axis 2 Misconfiguration: Insecure Message Security  A05-Security Misconfig  Medium  10/24/2016  2   57
axis2.xml   05.Lost Axis 2 Misconfiguration: Insecure Transport Receiver    A05-Security Misconfig  Medium  10/23/2016  2   58
axis2.xml   05.Lost Axis 2 Misconfiguration: Insecure Transport Receiver    A05-Security Misconfig  Medium  10/24/2016  2   57
UsageMetrics.java   05.Lost Often Misused: Authentication   A02-Broken Auth & Session Management    High    10/7/2016   4   74
UsageMetrics.java   05.Lost Path Manipulation   NA  High    10/18/2016  5   63
usageMetricsReport.jsp  05.Lost Cross-Site Request Forgery  A08-CSRF    Medium  10/25/2016  1   56
UsageMetricsState.java  05.Lost Path Manipulation   NA  High    10/18/2016  5   63
```

What I am trying to do is all the row.changed=="05.Lost". I want to take the old data and replace the NA for the retain.columns.

Thank you in advance

This does it as suggested by [lukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea):

```
 # modify data for retain.columns
  for (var in retain.columns)
    O[[var]] <- ifelse(M$is.new, as.character(M[[paste0(var, ".new")]]),
                     as.character(M[[paste0(var, ".old")]]))
```

Comment: _"I do not understand why it creates a dataframe with numbers in them?"_ - what exactly is the problem? I may increase the chances of getting answers if you'd minimize your code and exactly explain, what's going wrong or what result you would expect. In addidion, exchanging the 1st line by `download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kill3rbee/NTS-Test/master/test-2016-12-30.csv", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"));M <- read.csv(tf)` makes it easier to get things going.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and feedback. Did not think about just including download code. Done. I hope this helps

Comment: Unexpected conversion from character to numeric is mostly due to factors. Have you tried `ifelse(M$is.new, as.character(M[[paste0(var, ".new")]]),as.character(M[[paste0(var, ".old")]]))`?

Comment: lukeA, that was it. I really appreciate. You have a good eye. I would have done that, however because it was working with factors on other methods, did not even think i need to typecast. I will keep that in mind.